How to Enable Search for Nested Form Entries in GravityView (Gravity Forms)?
I'm using Gravity Forms with the Nested Forms Add-On (from Gravity Perks) to embed forms inside other forms. I'm displaying the parent form entries in GravityView, but I’m having trouble getting GravityView to search through the nested form entries.
Scenario:

I have a parent form that includes one or more nested forms.
The nested forms are being stored as entry meta in the parent form's entries.
When I search in GravityView, the results are limited to the parent form's fields, and it does not search inside the nested form entries.

What I've Tried:
I've attempted to modify the GravityView search query using the following code:
add_filter('gravityview/search/query', 'search_nested_form_entries', 10, 2);
function search_nested_form_entries( $search_criteria, $form_id ) {

    // Meta query to search through nested form entry meta
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => "input_2_1", 
            'value'   => $search_criteria['search_value'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    );

    if( isset( $search_criteria['field_filters'] ) ) {
        $search_criteria['field_filters']['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
    } else {
        $search_criteria['field_filters'] = array( 'meta_query' => $meta_query );
    }

    return $search_criteria;
}

The Problem:

Even after adding the custom code to modify the search query, GravityView is still not searching inside the nested form entries.
The search results only include parent form fields. I’ve ensured that the correct field ID for the nested form is being used.

My Setup:
WordPress version: 6.6.2
Gravity Forms version: 2.8.17
GravityView version: 2.28.0
Gravity Perks Nested Forms Add-On version: 1.1.32
What I Need: I want to enable searching through the nested form entries in GravityView. Is there a way to extend GravityView's search functionality to include fields from the nested forms? If so, how can this be achieved?
I've checked the Gravity Forms wp_gf_entry_meta table, and it appears that nested form entries are stored as serialized data. How can I properly modify the query to search within the nested form entry data?
Any help or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!
